# What kind of metrics are there to calculate "similarity" between two "root" nodes in a directed shallow graph?

Tags: python, graph, networkx, metrics, similarity

I have a graph build in networkX. This graph has two types of nodes, A and B. A-nodes can have a directed edge to B-nodes. B-nodes don't have any outgoing edges. Basically the graph represents references. So an A-node can reference to alot of B-nodes. Two A-nodes can have an edge to the same B-node.
I want to have a metric to calculate the "similarity" between two A-nodes.
I found that Bibliographic-Coupling works fine.
Co-Citation is not possible because the A-nodes don't have any ingoing edges.
Dispersion is also not posssible, because the B-Nodes don't have any edges between them.

I want to try out more metricies and compare them.
What kind of measurments can I use?

Comment: Quite hypothetical without this: Where's your code and minimum input of data and current output?

Answer (score 1):

Give [Jaccard Similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) a go. It takes the number of shared child nodes between two parent nodes, then divides it by the total number of unique child nodes between two nodes.

[image: formula for Jaccard similarity]

```py
import networkx as nx

# create a new graph
G = nx.DiGraph()

# add nodes of type A
G.add_nodes_from(['A1', 'A2', 'A3'])

# add nodes of type B
G.add_nodes_from(['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4'])

# add edges from A-nodes to B-nodes
G.add_edges_from([('A1', 'B1'), ('A1', 'B2'), ('A2', 'B2'), ('A2', 'B3'), ('A2', 'B4'), ('A3', 'B3'), ('A3', 'B4')])

# define function to compute Jaccard similarity between two A-nodes based on the B-nodes they are connected to
def jaccard_similarity(node1, node2):
    set1 = set(G.successors(node1))
    set2 = set(G.successors(node2))
    intersection = set1.intersection(set2)
    union = set1.union(set2)
    return len(intersection) / len(union)

# compute the Jaccard similarity between A1 and A2
similarity = jaccard_similarity('A1', 'A2')
print(f"The Jaccard similarity between A1 and A2 is: {similarity}")

# draw the plot

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# define the layout algorithm for the graph
pos = nx.circular_layout(G)

# draw the nodes and edges of the graph using the layout
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist=['A1', 'A2', 'A3'], node_color='r')
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist=['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4'], node_color='b')
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edgelist=G.edges(), edge_color='black', arrows=True)

# add labels to the nodes
labels = {node: node for node in G.nodes()}
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, labels)

# show the graph
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Output:
`The Jaccard similarity between A1 and A2 is: 0.25`
[image]